# Проблема с бесконечным циклом (JS)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, циклы

Добрый вечер.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, я новичок и пытаюсь написать алгоритм преобразования арабских чисел в римские.
Единственное, что пришло в голову: преобразовать последовательно тысячи, сотни, десятки и единицы (подразумевается, что больше четырехзначных чисел не будет). Реализовал следующим образом:

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
 var romNum = '';
 var numLength = num + '';
 while (num !== 0) {
   if (numLength.length == 4) {
     romNum += 'M' * (num / 1000);
     num = num % 1000;
   } else if (numLength.length == 3) {
     if ((num / 500) == 1) {
         romNum += 'D';
         num = num - 500;
       } else {
         romNum += 'C' * (num / 100);
         num = num % 100;
       }
   } else if (numLength.length == 2) {
     if ((num / 50) == 1) {
         romNum += 'L';
         num = num - 50;
       } else {
         romNum += 'X' * (num / 10);
         num = num % 10;
       }
   } else {
     if ((num / 5) == 1) {
         romNum += 'V';
         num = num - 5;
       } else {
         romNum += 'I' * num;
         num = 0;
      }
   }
 }
 return romNum;
}


convertToRoman(36);
```

Но, код не работает, цикл почему-то получается бесконечным. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять почему?

Comment: например потому. что у тебя `numLength.length` всегда постоянная

Comment: что ты хотел сделать умножением строки на число? например тут: `'I' * num`? если повторить символ несколько раз, то это так не работает

Comment: `'M' * (num / 1000);`
И что должно произойти после выполнения этой строчки?

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за ответ. Действительно, по невнимательности зачем-то вынес переменную из цикла. По строке: `'I' * num` - она должна повторять символ 'I' num раз. Если умножение строки на число не работает, как тогда повторить строку n-нное количество раз?

Comment: [.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) например

Comment: @АлександрИщенко Строка 'M' должна повторится (num / 1000) раз (т.е. на число равное количеству тысяч). Но, мне уже объяснили, что так не работает.

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, попробую сейчас